# Javascript Debugging - addEventListeners - Click events bogging down time wise performance issues

Tags: javascript, performance, addeventlistener

I could use some help debugging **addEventListeners**.

I would like some advice as to - how to keep track of these, and the resources they are using.
I am pretty sure the **addEventListeners** are my problem - as - I have a scenario where - when I add a certain number of these (more than 10), some click events then begin to take a longer than usual time. And other events will not fire.

Tracing these long **clickevent** times using **Safari** Webmaster Tools / "Timeline" -
I find that events such as "**mousdown**" (even a regular **onclick=""** type of event) response time jump from a few hundred milliseconds, to over 1.5 seconds. There is definitely a lull.

As well - in **FireFox** - A "window.print();" fails to trigger under this circumstance.
And strangely - if I place an "**alert()**" jest before the "**window.print()**;" function - the **time laps in clicking to close the alert - is enough to allow the "window.print();" to properly function.**

I'm assuming my bug has something to do with time management and perhaps an exponential increases of.
But I am uncertain how to best debug these addEventListeners.

I also have a number of searchable lists that create these **addEventListeners** on the fly - **as the person searches**. Perhaps I am not unloading them properly? For all I know there could be 10 million of them created.

I'll do my best to provide some code here - but what I would really like to learn, is how to:

- **manage**
- **keep track of**
- **debug**

these **addEventListeners**

I don't see them when I view source. I get nothing back in a way of errors in any console in any browser. It just seems like - once you create these - it is impossible to keep track of them and know what hey are or are not doing?

- How about - Is there a way to keep track of how many of them I have
  running?

---

- I call an Owners Pets from a database using PHP/MySQL and store the
  values in a javascript array.
- I then need to create tabs to select each pet. (each tab has an "X" to delete the tab and a listener for that as well)
- I loop the data and create the tabs and **addEventListeners** like this:

  ...

  ```
  for(var i=0; i<Pets_Array.length; i++){// Loop Existing and Active Pets Array Tabs

      if(Pets_Array[i]['VISITOR_IDENTITY_DELETED'] != "1"){// if pet not deleted

          // Create Pet Tabbing listeners
          document.getElementById('Visitor_Details_AUTOTAB_'+i).addEventListener("click", function(event){
              event.stopPropagation();
              Pet_Tabbing_Auto_Save = true;
              ID_Of_Pet_Tabbing = this.id;
              Tst_Sv_Comp('Pet_Tabbing');

          },false);


          // Create Pet DeleteX listeners

      <?php //if($ADMIN == true){// Only Admin ?>

              document.getElementById('VISITOR_IDENTITY_TAB_X_BUTTON_'+i).addEventListener("click", function(event){
                  event.stopPropagation();
                  Delete_Pet(this.id);


              },false);

      <?php //} // Only Admin ?>


          Last_AutoLoaded_Pet = i;

      }// END if pet not deleted

  }//END  Loop Existing and Active Pets Array Tabs
  ```

---

It seems strange that - I have hundreds of these **addEventListeners** with the lists and searches and tabs and functions on the page. And it all behaves fine - until you get over 10 of these tabs and **addEventListeners** that's enough to throw everything over the top and cause huge lag time???

---

Here is a look at my other code, creating the dynamic search lists that also utilize **addEventListeners** These are added during a search function as a few hundred search values are looped. This is also set up at init - to per-populate a list, with all values. Either way - there are a few lists with a few hundred values that are created into buttons - each needing a **addEventListeners**

.....

```
// Add dbble clck evnt listener
    document.getElementById(Who_To_Search_BREED_or_VET_CLINIC_G+'_'+key).addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#Add_'+Who_To_Search_BREED_or_VET_CLINIC_G+'_Button').hide();        
        Handle_Double_Clicks(this.id);
    },false);
```

---

I am also using a number of **image-load listeners** that are inside functions that are actuated by the tab clicks - to load the pets profile image.

i.e...

```
Tab_Click_Function(){

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = '../application_images/Owners/'+G_OWNER+'/Pets/'+G_Pet_Selected+'/main/'+Main_Profile_Image_For_Pets_Array_G["PET_"+G_Pet_Selected];// Visitor_Profile_Picture image;

  image.addEventListener("load", function(){

   document.getElementById('PRINT_CAMPER_PROFILE_PHOTO').src = image.src;// show image now that is has loaded into the cache

  }, false);




}
```

---

I believe that I am - somewhere here - not properly managing these. I believe that with some help understanding the best way to keep track, manage, and debug these - I will have better performance with this code - and with future code.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because I don't believe it's exactly what you're looking for, but I though I would throw out a suggestion. Using jQuery.on you can attach the event listener to the parent element. For instance: 

$('#parent').on('click', 'child', function(e) {};

The idea is that there is only 1 event being bound and it is relying on event bubbling. I'm sure that this same idea can be applied via vanilla javascript, although the code will be more verbose. I hope this give you some ideas.

Comment: @mikekavouras +1, it looks like he's already using jQuery elsewhere in the code too.

Comment: Thanks for this... It does sound like the answer bellow... and again a good solution... but again I would like to ask... Is there a way to track / trace the ones I have now? Or any eventhandler for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does not take very many (even simple) event handlers to run into this problem on older browsers like IE 6.  To solve this, you need to change your approach a bit. Create one event handler and attach it to the parent DOM element that holds all the children you are currently creating handlers for. Then, in that single handler, examine the target of the event and invoke the code you originally intended, in your case maybe it looks like a save.  This approach also has another added benefit: when you add or remove children to the parent, you don't need to register or unregistered any handlers.

Comment: Thanks for this. It does sound like a great solution. Do you know... Is there a way to track / trace the ones I have now? Or any eventhandler for that matter. It just seems that the typical methods of tracing variables and functions and the number of these can get lost this way. Is there a way to determine how many I have running?